# Как объявить массив указателей на функции возвращающие различные типы?

Tags: c

Как объявить массив указателей на функции возвращающие различные типы?

Comment: Контрвопрос: а как вы собираетесь вызывать функцию из этого массива?

Comment: while((tmp=fun1())!=0){array_fun2[tmp]();}

Comment: используйте массив структур с двумя полями, первое типа int, где будет указан "номер сигнатуры", а второе типа `void*`, где собственно будет храниться указатель.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Массив на то и массив , что указывает на один тип и неважно `int` `char` или `int (*)(void)`  , Но можно создать массив указателей на один тип функций, а при вызове указывать другой тип

```
int fun_0(int);
int fun_1(int,int);
int fun_2(int,int,int);

int (*array_fun[])(int) = {fin_0,(int (*)(int))fin_1,(int (*)(int))fun_2};

int (*fun)(int,int) = (int (*)(int,int))array_fun[1];
*fun(3,5);
```